# Machine learning tutorials / examples on data sets larger than a terabyte

Tags: machine-learning, references, feature-selection, large-data, aggregation

I am trying to gather a list of practical ML examples / tutorials on more than a terabyte of data. I'm particularly interested in feature extraction from large data sets that involves aggregation (the actual ML algorithm could ultimately be run on a much smaller set of data). Does anyone know of any blog posts / ebooks / etc. that walk through an example on a public data set greater than a terabyte?

Comment: Look for the large hadron collider dataset plus the toolset they use. I believe they have just released another huge batch of data to the public.

Comment: have you checked this course in coursera? https://www.coursera.org/course/mmds

Comment: Check out the databricks product: https://databricks.com/

In the free cluster, you get around 6GB of memory and they have a huge Wikipedia dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any such tutorial, but I ultimately would question the interest of it. I can see no case where there is a need for a terabyte of data (within the context of a tutorial, of course). It will only cause longer running times, and I believe significant "big data" results can easily be gathered from a few GBs of data.

Though, the MAWILab experiment (http://www.fukuda-lab.org/mawilab/) might provide what you need. Its captures of IP traffic taken for the last 15 years on a transpacific backbone router. There an anomaly classification run over it, with different methods, and as such can serve as a ground truth example to your needs.